# Allotropes of hydrogen

Tags: hydrogen, allotropes

Is it possible to chemically bond 8 hydrogen atoms together to form an allotrope like $\ce{H8}$?

Comment: No, unless maybe in really extreme conditions. Why you ask?

Comment: I just thought of the idea, what would it create if its even possible to create...

Comment: OK, there was kinda similar thing with oxygen. It was found to exist in $\ce{O8}$ molecules under very high pressure,  so maybe hydrogen also does, but AFAIK such molecules were not detected.

Comment: Trihydrogen hydride would be the one I could think of

Comment: The only thing I found is [Chemical Bonding of New Allotropes of Hydrogen and Its Implications to Fuel Science, A. C. Angus](https://bit.ly/2vMcPCA) which screams opinion article but maybe someone has the time to look into it.

Comment: @Linear Christmas they really don't seen to back up their claims in any way. Also, even their suggestions seem to imply that these allotropes would only exist in the sun.

Comment: @Tyberius That what I was afraid of. The fact that they would exist soley in a sun is not a really a problem in itself because extreme conditions are required either way. But the credibility is disqualifying matter. Thanks for checking into it! Perhaps looking at some astrophysics / nuclear physics textbook is also warranted to be sure?